# scala semicolon inference example

Tags: scala

The "Programming in scala" introduces the rules of semicolon inference:

In short, a line ending is treated as a semicolon unless one of the following conditions is true:

1. The line in question ends in a word that would not be legal as the end of a statement, such as a period or an infix operator.
2. The next line begins with a word that cannot start a statement.
3. The line ends while inside parentheses(...) or brackets[...], because these cannot contain multiple statements anyway.

But I can't find an example that in the second condition,who can give an example?
I have tried the following code because * cannot start a statement,but it failed!

```
    1 * 2
    *3
```

Comment: `Some(2).map { f
 => f * 2
}`

Sorry, SO comments loose indentation. Anyway... if you put the `=>` on the new line

Comment: What makes you think that `*` cannot start a statement? Please, re-read http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters carefully: it says (**bold** emphasis mine): "The tokens that can begin a statement are **all Scala tokens** *except* the following delimiters and reserved words: `catch`, `else`, `extends`, `finally`, `forSome`, `match`, `with`, `yield`, `,`, `.`, `;`, `:`, `=`, `=>`, `<-`, `<:`, `<%`, `>:`, `#`, `[`, `)`, `]`, `}`". Note that `*` does not appear in that list, and why would it? A method call is perfectly legal starting a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The "Programming in scala" introduces the rules of semicolon inference:
>
> In short, a line ending is treated as a semicolon unless one of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. The line in question ends in a word that would not be legal as the end of a statement, such as a period or an infix operator.
> 2. The next line begins with a word that cannot start a statement.
> 3. The line ends while inside parentheses(...) or brackets[...], because these cannot contain multiple statements anyway.

Note that this is a rather simplified view. The full rules are in [section 1.2 *Newline Characters*](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters) of the [Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters).

> But I can't find an example that in the second condition,who can give an example?

According to the SLS:

> The tokens that can begin a statement are **all Scala tokens** *except* the following delimiters and reserved words:
>
> - `catch`
> - `else`
> - `extends`
> - `finally`
> - `forSome`
> - `match`
> - `with`
> - `yield`
> - `,`
> - `.`
> - `;`
> - `:`
> - `=`
> - `=>`
> - `<-`
> - `<:`
> - `<%`
> - `>:`
> - `#`
> - `[`
> - `)`
> - `]`
> - `}`

So, one example could be:

```
return 42
.toString()
```

This is equivalent to

```
return 42.toString(); // returns the `String` "42"
```

and *not*

```
return 42;  // returns the `Int` 42
.toString() // dead code
```

> I have tried the following code because * cannot start a statement,but it failed!
>
> ```
> 1 * 2
> *3
> ```

What makes you think that `*` cannot start a statement? Please, re-read the spec carefully. A method call is perfectly legal starting a statement:

```
foo(bar)
```

is valid, and so is

```
*(3)
```

Ergo, `*` *can* start a statement. Full example:

```
object Test
  def test = {
    1 * 2
    *(3)
  }

  def *(x: Int) = {
    println(x)
    x + 1
   }
 }

Test.test
// 3
//=> res0: Int = 4
```